# Generalized Fubini's theorem

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-measure

Is there a generalized Fubini's theorem, which allows one to conclude that, for example,
$$\iint_D \frac{dA}{x^2 - 2xy + 1} = \iint_{-1}^1 \frac{dx \, dy}{x^2 - 2xy + 1} = \iint_{-1}^1 \frac{dy \, dx}{x^2 - 2xy + 1},$$
where $D = \{(x, y) : -1 \leq x \leq 1, -1 \leq y \leq 1\}$, or course. Note that the integrand is not continuous at $(1, 1)$ and $(-1, -1)$, so we cannot apply the standard [Fubini's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FubiniTheorem.html). However, the set of discontinuities is finite (so it has zero measure). Yet, I do not think $1/(x^2 - 2xy + 1)$ is integrable, so we cannot use the measure-theoretic Fubini's theorem either.

Can we apply [this](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~jverstra/20e-lecture16.pdf) (1st page) formulation of Fubini's theorem?

Comment: Tonelli's theorem work for this particular one at least, since it's always positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $x^2-2xy+1\geq (x\pm1)^2\geq 0$ (the sign is $+$ or $-$ depending on the sign of $x$), you can apply [Tonelli's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions).

Comment: Quick question: Can we apply [this](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~jverstra/20e-lecture16.pdf) (1st page) formulation of Fubini's theorem? I have never seen this formulation in the literature.

Comment: At first glance, yes, we can.