# Reference Request: Fubini's theorem for non-negative functions

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, reference-request

I have never seen [this](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~jverstra/20e-lecture16.pdf) (1st page) formulation of Fubini's theorem in the literature. Does anyone know where I can find it? In every calculus book (e.g. Apostol, Courant, etc.) I looked, the authors always assume that the function $f$ is *integrable*. I could find a single author who states (and proves) Fubini's theorem for *non-negative* functions. I know there is a measure-theoretic Fubini's theorem for *non-negative* functions that are not necessarily integrable, namely, Tonelli's theorem. However, I am looking for something elementary, something that does not involve measure theory.

I want to justify equalities similar to the one in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856734/generalized-fubinis-theorem) question without invoking theorems from measure theory.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: But the theorem I am looking for is stated [here](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~jverstra/20e-lecture16.pdf) (1st page). Do you think it is not correct?

Comment: Well my point was more that things are much better suited in the measure theoretic context. I've never seen any non-trivial non-measure theoretic approach to Fubini or Tonelli. I've seen the results quoted in multivariable texts but without proof. From what I have pieced together, it's usually taken from the measure theoretic context and presented in the context they care about or functions are assumed to be continuous (or almost continuous) so that proofs are simple.

Comment: @glebovg: it looks to me that the notes you link to are assuming $f$ is *continuous* (read everything on the first page) except at a finite set of discontinuities.

Comment: "... such that $f$ has only finitely many discontinuities in $D$."  So it's continuous a.e.  Also, all of its Riemann sums are absolutely convergent if they're convergent at all...

Comment: @symplectomorphic Yes, that is enough for me. I am looking for a book which states the theorem in the notes.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Almost continuous and non-negative is enough for me. Do you know of a book which states Fubini's theorem for almost continuous and non-negative functions?

Comment: I want to justify equalities similar to the one in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856734/generalized-fubinis-theorem) question without invoking theorems from measure theory.